# How to redirect specified packet using WFPSampler of WFP (Windows Filtering Platform )

Tags: c++, proxy, wfp

Could you tell me how to redirect internet connection to local proxy in my PC ?

I got WFPSampler from the below URL.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/network/trans/WFPSampler

I'd like to redirect internet connection to local proxy in my PC using the WFPSampler without changing proxy setting of IE. 
My system is the below.

[System] 
OS: Windows 8.1 (192.168.1.1) 
Local proxy: squid (port:3128)

[Background] 
I performed the below command. But it did not work.

WFPSampler.exe -s BASIC_PACKET_MODIFICATION -l FWPM_LAYER_OUTBOUND_TRANSPORT_V4 -ipla 127.0.0.1 -iprp 80 -mpdp 3128 -ipp TCP -v 
Thank you for any help

Regards, 
Y.N

Answer (score 1):

Consider using FWPM_LAYER_ALE_CONNECT_REDIRECT_V4 layer as it is designed for the purpose of redirection.